# Excel: How to copy a row if it contains certain text to another worksheet (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm looking to use a marco that would be able to search a column in said sheet and if certain text is found - in my case the word "FAIL" - copy that entire rows data/formatting and paste it into another sheet - sheet 4 in my case - along with any other rows that contained that specific text.

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

i have been using this code but it only copy pastes one row then stops rather than going through and copying any rows with "FAIL"

```
Sub Test()
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("H:H")
  If Cell.Value = "FAIL" Then
    matchRow = Cell.Row
    Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
    Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets(4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets(4).Select
   End If
Next 
End Sub
```

First post and brand new to VBA so apologies if too vague.

Comment: Going through https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683 will solve your problem.

Comment: More links for you: [Never Assume The Worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet#t=201707200839270059847). The problem is that after first `FAIL` you are **taking** data from `Sheets(4)`. You could find that bug by debugging your code: put text cursor within your code and press F8 to run it line by line. Changes will be visible in your worksheet immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below (explanation inside the code as comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets(1)
    ' loop column H untill last cell with value (not entire column)
    For Each Cell In .Range("H1:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value = "FAIL" Then
             ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(4).Rows(Cell.Row)
        End If
    Next Cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The code runs fast, however it keeps the space between the line. Meaning if there is a row is going to be jumped the new table has empty rows that has been jumped

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim matchRow As Long

    With Worksheets(1)    
        For Each Cell In .Range("H:H")
            If Cell.Value = "FAIL" Then
                matchRow = .Cell.Row
                .Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
                .Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
                Selection.Copy        
                Worksheets(4).Select
                Worksheets(4).Rows(matchRow).Select
                Worksheets(4).Paste
                .Select
            End If
        Next        
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem in your code is that you do not reference the worksheets all the time correctly. Thus it does not work correctly.

As a 2. step, you can try to avoid all the selections in your code, it is a best practice to avoid using either Select or Activate in Excel VBA.

Comment: I receive an error "object doesn't support this property or method" for If .Cell.Value = "FAIL" Then

Comment: That's because of the naming you are using (and thus, I am using as well). Do not name your variables `Cell`, because it may get confused with the Object `Cell`, because of the same name. Now it is fixed - I removed the point before it.