# Excel: How to use Copy Paste command to selected sheet area (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

Extended Question from- 
[Excel: How to copy a row if it contains certain text to another worksheet (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209392/excel-how-to-copy-a-row-if-it-contains-certain-text-to-another-worksheet-vba/45209759#45209759)

I'm looking to modify the below code so that it's able to copy from sheet 2 to sheet 4, pasted adjacent (L:U)? see pictures.

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eKHi.jpg)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets(1)
' loop column H untill last cell with value (not entire column)
For Each Cell In .Range("H1:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Cell.Value = "FAIL" Then
         ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
        .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(4).Rows(Cell.Row)
    End If
Next Cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment Reply with picture [pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbtOj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets(1)
' loop column H untill last cell with value (not entire column)
For Each Cell In .Range("H1:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Cell.Value = "FAIL" Then
         ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
        .Range("A" & Cell.Row & ":J" & Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(4).Range("L" & Sheets(4).Cells(Sheets(4).Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End If
Next Cell
End With

End Sub
```

Macro to copy links:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets(1)
' loop column H untill last cell with value (not entire column)
For Each Cell In .Range("H1:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Cell.Value = "FAIL" Then
        .Range("A" & Cell.Row & ":J" & Cell.Row).Copy
         ' Paste as Links requires to select a destination cell
        Sheets(4).Range("L" & Sheets(4).Cells(Sheets(4).Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
    End If
Next Cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: does the trick however when i click the grab marco twice it just pastes same data underneath?

Comment: i added a picture (pic3) of result

Comment: @Hufflegigans Every time you run this macro it will copy all data. I added another solution. It will copy links to your source data, so there will be no need to update it (I can't test it ATM, hope it works).